# Jqassistant scan artefakts from ivy repository

Tags: jqassistant

Is it possible to scan artifacts from an ivy repository?
I searched in the Documentation put only found a Solution for maven repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently jQAssistant supports only Maven repositories. If you are familiar with Ivy you can use the plugin API of jQAssistant to write a scanner for Ivy repositories. We would support you if you need help.